# Determine whether the given set S is a subspace of the vector space V

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

(a) V=R^n, and S is the set of solutions to the homogeneous linear system Ax=0 where A is a fixed m×n matrix.

(b) V=P^4, and S is the subset of P subscript 4 consisting of all polynomials of the form p(x)=ax^3+bx

(c) V is the vector space of all real-valued functions defined on the interval (−∞,∞), and S is the subset of V consisting of those functions satisfying f(0)=0.

(d) V=P subscript 3, and S is the subset of P subscript 3 consisting of all polynomials of the form p(x)=x^2+c.

(e) V=C^2(R) (twice continuously differentiable functions), and S is the subset of V consisting of those functions satisfying the differential equation y′′=0.

(f) V=R^4 and S is the set of vectors of the form (0,x subscript 2,4,x subscript 4).

(g) V is the vector space of all real-valued functions defined on the interval [a,b], and S is the subset of V consisting of those functions satisfying f(a)=4.

Currently, I think A and C are subspace of vector V, not sure about the others

Comment: Please use latex to type your question.

Comment: Jabbol123, using MathJax will help make your question more appealing to read. The community is becoming a little too strict lately and unfortunately some members are too quick to downvote without giving feedback and how to improve postings making the environment feel somewhat hostile. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a link that guides you through the basics of MathJax. Give it a try.